# ASUS Tranformer 101G won't charge, but USB connection works

Tags: battery, tablet, charging

My ASUS TF101G tablet has suddenly stopped charging. If I plug it into the wall (dock+tablet), it won't charge. I tried plugging just the tablet into the wall, it won't charge. I tried just plugging it into a laptop with the same cable, still won't charge. But the laptop "sees" that the tablet is plugged in, and I can interact with it, just no charging.

What am I to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can pop open the power adapter that plugs into the outlet and reset it.

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately doesn't help...